# Generate/Extract for Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, website-design, svg, workflow

Is there a way (plugin, add-on, etc) to export assets from Illustrator the way one does with Photoshop Generate? I'm finding myself spending a lot of time meticulously separating everything into many many artboards, and it would be very helpful if I could just have each group output to a different subfolder (dare I say, even exported at different sizes), and then be able to drop the elements into my layouts (or animations...or link them in my code). I believe that Illustrator and SVG is clearly the future of web design/dev, but the workflow (as it stands) is atrocious. I've done a bit of digging online to no avail. The artboards do work, but they are massively tedious to separate, and it doesn't allow separation of overlapping elements the way I'd like.

---

P.S.: *Any* useful tools for speeding up a *vector => website* workflow are also very welcome. I find myself spending way too much time on the export as my procedure stands now, and any way I can streamline it is a step forward!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Slices` in Illustrator to export images using `Save For Web`.

[image: Slices in Illustrator]

I’d advise against using Illustrator to export image assets. It has many issues, like non-dithered gradients, worse shape antialiasing than Photoshop (and other apps), and other problems.

Comment: Thanks for that! I mostly want to use it for SVG output, so those concerns aren't a huge worry in this context. Some exciting stuff going on with the whole SVG world right now. It would be nice to see Adobe start taking Illustrator seriously as a web authoring tool. They're finally getting it together with Photoshop just as everything moves to vector. Classic!

Thanks @marc !

Comment: Just checking that you know this: Photoshop can export SVGs using Generator. There are definitely limitations on what’s possible, but for single colour icons and simpler web interface assets, it’s a good option if want automated SVG exporting.

Answer (score 1):

Using Adobe CC I design assets in illustrator then export to Photoshop via my Adobe Creative Cloud libraries. Photoshop is hands down way better than Sketch3 to export files, particularly when file size matters.

1 - Design in illustrator on a pixel grid and every asset on a separate layer

2 - I select the asset using its layer

3 - I use my Adobe CC library to export the asset Library Panel / Add Graphic [button] and give an appropriate name to my asset (ex.: AssetName@1x.png) that reflect my final export format

4 - I create a document in photoshop and drop all the asset I saved in my library. Each asset will show as a layer with the name I gave it.

5 - Select the layers to export then Layer Panel / Export As. The layer name suffix automatically selects the format.

Answer (score 1):

I found the [Smart Layers Export](https://creative.adobe.com/addons/products/2955) script a lifesaver. You can export specific layers/artboards to multiple formats at once, svg included, and export at different sizes (@2x, etc).

Answer (score -1):

What about this little plugin?
http://www.kodlian.com/apps/magic-exporter

Comment: Please include some description on what is behind the link. In general one line answers are frowned upon.